# Can I delete one single signature from file?

Tags: c#, x509certificate2

I'm writing a program to sign files using X509 Certificates and .NET framework classes. My users can sign the same file without any problem (like a revision process). So, a file may contain one or more signatures PKCS#7.

I'm using the CMSSigner class and I don't encrypt the file - just sign it.

**But a user ask me the following: "By mistake I signed a file and I would like to take off my signature from that file. Can I do this?"**

I see no problem when the file has only the user's signature (only one X509 certificate within), but I'm not sure if I can unsign the file if it has many signatures there. The routine that I utilize to delete a signature from file picks the original data and, in that case, I loss all of its signatures within.

So, using .NET classes (X509Certificate2), can I just delete the user's signature from that file, without the loss the other certificates there?

Thanks for any help.